"Walking" the parent/children hierarchy tree
I have trouble understanding the usage of the hierarchy tree in BPY.
As I understand, Blender doesn't offer such a tree in the API so how can I deal with parent/children relations?
Consider the following example:

The node "Ground" is the first node above the actual meshes but it's name is not known.

How do I find out which is the first node directly above the mesh nodes? (The first parent)
How do I know how many nodes are above the Ground node? (It's name is not known.)
How can I get rid of all nodes above the Ground node?

In other software, walking the tree is simple but without a relationship tree I'm lost.
bpy.ops.object.parent_clear on the meshes would remove Ground also and this is not what I want.
Are there any best practice methods in BPY to work with hierarchies?

This probably won't get any flashiness points on CodeNinja.com but it does the trick.

import bpy
from bpy import data as D
from bpy import context as C
from pathlib import Path 

object = C.object

# get the object above
# if object is root then p is None 
p = object.parent 

# only children parented directly to this object 
direct_children = object.children 

# all children below this object in the hierarchy 
all_children = object.children_recursive 

def get_parent_info(obj):
    num_child = len(obj.children)
    next_obj = obj.children[0]
    return num_child, next_obj

# How do I find out which is the first node directly above the mesh nodes? (The first parent)
def get_ground_object(root_obj):
    num_child, next_obj = get_parent_info(root_obj)
    while num_child == 1 and next_obj.type == "EMPTY":
        num_child, next_obj = get_parent_info(next_obj)
    return next_obj.parent
    

# How do I know how many nodes are above the Ground node? (It's name is not known.)
def get_parents_above(obj):
    parents = []
    par = obj.parent
    while par.parent is not None:
        parents.append(par)
        par = par.parent
    parents.append(par)
    return parents
    
# How can I get rid of all nodes above the Ground node?
def clear_parent_keep_transform(obj):
    parents = get_parents_above(obj)
    # this assumes you want to keep the object where it is in WS
    obj_loc = obj.matrix_world.translation.copy()
    obj.parent = None
    obj.matrix_world.translation = obj_loc
    
    for p in parents:
        D.objects.remove(p, do_unlink=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # I'm assuming you at least know the root object
    root_obj = D.objects['Level1']
    go = get_ground_object(root_obj) # -> <bpy_struct, Object("Ground") at 0x000002674F266B08>
    parents = get_parents_above(go) # -> [bpy.data.objects['Level2'], bpy.data.objects['Level1']]
    np = len(parents) # -> 2
    clear_parent_keep_transform(go)

```


Wow! That's a great tool box! Thanks a lot! A bit more complex as walking a tree but you helped me a lot understanding this topic! And a big thanks also for your comments referring to my example!
